# Make sure that page always gets loaded in an iframe

Tags: php, jquery, html, iframe

I'm using a 3rd party booking system in an iframe in my site. 
When users make a booking, they receive an email with a confirmation link that points directly to the booking page (that I normally show inside the iframe). So the user sees only the calendar instead of the entire page with the calendar in an iframe.

Is there a way to check if the page is loading inside an iframe and if not, load a parent page around it?

Comment: iframes.... brrrr... they're so 90s :P

Comment: What you are asking can be done, but you will need at sequence for it all to be done.

Comment: I know, i hate iframes too but we had to include this calendar and it seemed like the only option... @NULL: please suggest the sequence in an answer and I will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you get the point:

**iframe-page.html**

```
<script>
    if ( window.top == window.self ) {
        location.replace('site.html?path=' + encodeURIComponent(location.href));
    }
</script>
```

**site.html**

```
<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
<script>
    // site.html?path=lol.html -> lol.html
    var path = location.href.split('?').pop().split('path=').pop().split('&').shift(),
        iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');

    if ( path ) {
        iframe.setAttibute('src', decodeURIComponent(path));
    } 
</script>
```

But you will maybe get problems with the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Comment: This looks nice, I'll give it a try & let you know.

Answer (score 0):

**In javascript** **window.top** needs to be like the **window**, but into an iframe window don't is equal window.top.

```
<script>if( window.top != window ) window.top.location = 'PARENT_URL';</script>
```